# NotificationCompat.Builder is deprecated

Tags: java, android, deprecated

```
private void sendNotification(Context context, String dnsModel) {
    Intent intentAction = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    intentAction.putExtra("dnsModel", dnsModel);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, intentAction, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.dns_changer_ico_inverse)
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.service_ready))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_vpn_lock_black_24dp, context.getString(R.string.turn_on), pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();

    notificationManager.notify(1903, notification);

}
```

I've tried using `NotificationCompat.Builder(Context context, String channelId)` but I'm getting more errors on `Context context` and I have absolutely no ideea on hot to add a ``channelId`.

Comment: plz try to use any string as channelId

Comment: I did, and is telling me that ``Context context`` should have ``, or )``

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Comment: add your channelId to NotificationCompat.Builder. channelId can be any string. Just make a new String contain your channelId. Make sure to put channelId after context. i.e. NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a notification channel is not that hard.
Here is some code: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels#CreateChannel

You can execute that code in your MainActivity or your Application class on app startup.

Once you created the channel id, you can use it with
`NotificationCompat.Builder(Context context, String channelId)`

**EDIT**

The CHANNEL_ID is a simple String.
You can for example add this to a constants file:

```
public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "your.package.name.notificationChannelId"
```

You can now use this constants hwen creating your notification channel and when calling `NotificationCompat.Builder(Context context, String channelId)`

Comment: It doesn't answer my question https://imgur.com/OoHpx56

Comment: That CHANNEL_ID is a constant string you have to create, the same you'll use when sending the notification.

Comment: @LuTz Found it ?

Comment: Added the code to my ``MainActivity.java`` like this https://imgur.com/nIws9xR

But, it still doesn't see it on my ``BootReceiver.java``https://imgur.com/j3l71IQ

Comment: In you BootReceiver.java you should be using NotificationCompat.Builder(context, MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID).